# Get root project name in library

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is it somehow possible to get root project name in library module when building root project? For example:

mainProject has one module(library) project included with:

```
compile project(path: ':lib-subproject')
```

now in this lib-subproject i want to flavour builds based on root project name. I already tried with `getRootProject.getName()` in my lib-subproject gradle but this gives me the name of this library.

Comment: What is your `settings.gradle` and directory layout? Just curious, as I'm not sure what you mean by "root project".

Answer (score 5):

You can access the root Projects name with:
`rootProject.name`

In your example you tried to use the probably undefined property `getRootProject`, but you most likely meant to use the method `getRootProject()`.

You can find more information about the properties and methods of the project in [the offical gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html).